# Could not Get ClusteredIndexSeek for a where with primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a sample table with the clustered index as below and inserted 1500 records.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_mytable_myid  ON dbo.MyTable(myid)
```

When I execute the below query, I could see the execution plan having Clustered Index Scan instead of seek. I am not sure why the index table is scanned.

```
SELECT myid FROM dbo.MyTable  WHERE myid=1666
```

[image]

Comment: you can use forceseek hint to force sql server to seek an index

Comment: Thanks for indicating the hint. problem identified.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies. I identified that through the warning symbol in execution plan and found that myid field is actually a varchar and an implicit conversion happens, which forces to do a scan and not a seek.

Upon querying  like this
SELECT myid FROM dbo.MyTable  WHERE myid='1666'
it does the seek.

Comment: That's not what I was expecting. If the myID column is indeed varchar, I'd have expected SQL to implicitly convert the static value (i.e. 1666) to a varchar and then run with that (as opposed to doing the implicit conversion on the table side of the equality). My suspicion for why you were seeing the scan is that your table is small; 1500 rows is likely only a couple of pages and for small tables, it's just more efficient to scan the whole table than to figure out which of a small number of pages it will need to read.

Comment: @BenThul I understand your point. However, It does seek for the same number of records when querying as myid='1666'. What I understand is seek could be done  by a binary tree search, which will be unpredictable if the datatypes are in mismatch. Hence index scan would have happened.

Comment: Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks for discussing.

Comment: It depends on what side of the equality the implicit conversion is happening on. Think of it if you did the conversion yourself. `where myID = convert(varchar, 1666)` is going to do just fine whereas `where convert(int, myID) = 1666` won't.